# How do I detect multiple overlapping cycles in a directed graph using Depth First Search (DFS)?

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, cycle, directed-graph

Image of Directed Graph with Overlapping Cycles

[image]

There are 8 cycles in total that need to be detected:-

1-2-3-4-5-1
1-2-3-6-5-1
1-2-7-6-5-1
1-2-7-4-5-1

1-8-7-6-5-1
1-8-7-4-5-1
1-8-3-4-5-1
1-8-3-6-5-1

I understand how to use WHITE, GREY AND BLACK SETS along with a boolean visited array/stack but I am still struggling with the logic. Would appreciate any help, I don't need a detailed description of how to code it, just how to work the algorithm (modified DFS) and maybe pseudo code. Again thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

The key to detect a cycle in a **directed graph** is the grey color (which means the node and its neighbors are being explored). 
If one of those neighbors has another connection to the grey node, you have a cycle. 
So if an explored node has a grey neighbor, you have a cycle. 
In other words, if a node is re-visited before all its neighbors were explored you have a cycle.

Comment: Thanks c0der ! I understand that but it still doesn't explain how the algorithm can detect those 8 cycles as there are many overlaps. I ran through the DFS algorithm with the starting point as 1 and although it manages to search the entire graph, I'm not quite sure how I can extract the 8 cycles from the algorithm. I can identify 1 cycle based on random node selection but after that the search comes to an end when all the vertices are BLACK without giving me the rest of the cycles

Comment: **"search the entire graph"** is key. Say the first dfs path is `1-2-3-4-5` , when you get to 5  and find it has a grey neighbor (1) you store the cycle found (1-2-3-4-5-1).  Than you backtrack and continue searching until next cycle found.

Comment: Yes, search the entire graph.  But also *clear the visited state when backtracking.*  That way when you reach node 5 the second time (1-2-3-6-5) you continue on to 1 and find the second cycle, and so on.

Comment: When backtracking, if I clear the visited state i.e. change the colour of the nodes back to WHITE, then wouldn't that node become unexplored again. So then while forward tracking, it would search the same path again because the nodes have all been changed back to WHITE except for Node 1. For example, 1st cycle detected is 1-2-3-4-5-1. Then we backtrack back 1 to 5 to 4 to 3 and change the colours of 5 and 4 from GREY back to WHITE. Then from Node 3 when we look for unexplored nodes, wouldn't we find Node 4 again because its colour has been changed back to WHITE?

Comment: Sorry c0der, I can't mark the question as answered just yet. I am fairly new to algorithm development so please bare with me.

Comment: I am very close to understanding, just require an answer to my last comment

Comment: Please note that the policy here is one concise programming question per post.  (I don't thing the problem with backtracking is real: yes, when you get to node 3 the 2nd time you'll explore it again, but as part of a different path. First path: 1-2-3-4-5-1 . Second path 1-8-3-4-5-1). If you do encounter a problem post a new question, preferably with [mcve]

Comment: Yes but how do you know its a different path until you have reached the end of the path. So it is not possible to have a condition which allows that branch to be traversed again but at the same time stops the older cycles from being re traversed